# Restrict access login for some mins PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have my form below.. I want an to perform an operation if that the user enters the wrong password for 3 times, after his account is locked for some minutes.. How do I achieve that in my form?

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];


$connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');

mysql_selectdb('lr') or die('Couldnt find database');

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($numrows !=0){

   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

        $dbuser = $row['username'];
        $dbpass = $row['password'];

   }

   if ($username == $dbuser && $password == $dbpass){

        $_SESSION['username'] = $dbuser;
            if($_SESSION['username']){
        echo 'Welcome ' . $_SESSION['username'] . ' ! <br>';
        echo 'Click <a href = "index.php"> here </a> to log out !';


            }
   } else
        echo 'Incorrect Username or Password Combinations ';

} else
    die('That user does not exist'); 

}


?>
```

Comment: Insert summat into the database to achieve this - like the last time the person tried is it is within the window of opportunity

Comment: How? I didnt uderstand you

Comment: For a start you have a problem with sql injection. You need to record the fact that that username has tried in x seconds ago.

Comment: How to do that? Can you provide me with a snippet?

Comment: Get the last time they tried (you store that bit in the database). If older that 3 mins bung in the current time. If not fetch the last value. If they fail and younger that 3 mins put the last time they tried into the future

Answer (score 1):

Like another user said before you are vulnerable to SQL injection. Always VALIDATE user input!

As to your issue, you can use the database for this, then someone could block another user's account easily. You can also use sessions variables instead. You only need to record in session the number of failed logins. After 3 fail you can set a session variable with a timestamp of when the user will be allowed to login again (current timestamp + X) and before running the SQL check if the time as passed.
If a user logs-in sucessfuly you should clear or reset those session variables.
(sorry i dont have time making you and example, but it's quite easy to implement.)

**Made in mousepad**, not tested in any way but it will give you some hints i hope.

```
<?php
session_start();
define('MAX_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS',3);

if(isset($_SESSION['loginTimeout']) && $_SESSION['loginTimeout']<time()) {
    echo "You used all login attempts. Try again in a little while.";
    exit() // ups, forgot about this :)
}

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');

    mysql_selectdb('lr') or die('Couldnt find database');

    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    $bFail = false;

    if($numrows !=0){

       while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

            $dbuser = $row['username'];
            $dbpass = $row['password'];

       }

       if ($username == $dbuser && $password == $dbpass){
    unset($_SESSION['loginTimeout']);
            $_SESSION['username'] = $dbuser;
            if($_SESSION['username']){
                echo 'Welcome ' . $_SESSION['username'] . ' ! <br>';
                echo 'Click <a href = "index.php"> here </a> to log out !';
                    }
       } else {
          echo 'Incorrect Username or Password Combinations ';
          $bFail = true;
       }

    } else {
        die('That user does not exist');
        $bFail = true; 
    }

    if($bFail) {
        if(isset($_SESSION['loginAttempts'])) $_SESSION['loginAttempts']++;
        else $_SESSION['loginAttempts'] = 1;

        if($_SESSION['loginAttempts']>MAX_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS) {
           // one hour timeout
           $_SESSION['loginTimeout'] = time() + 1*60*60;
        }
    }
}




?>
```

Comment: Please provide with a snippet ? :/

Comment: @yetin - Guess you want somebody to write the code for you. Kinda not the right place. Pointers have been given

Comment: @Jorge I have tested it.. But when I login more than 3 times with incorrect pw, it does not block me

Comment: did you add the exit i added last?

Comment: Yes I added the exit(); 

First I have the my index.php which contains the fields and buttons.. When I click submit, it directs me another page if the password is correct. 
But how do I block the access after 3 failed attempts?

Comment: Sorry, dont have more time to create a full system. The hints are all there, read each line and learn what is does and you should be able to make it suit your needs.